# How to migrate Windows accounts to asp.net membership

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

I am working on an old ASP.NET application whose end users authenticate with a local Windows account (no domain). We want to switch to using membership (via `aspnet_regsql`), and move the application to a new server. **What's the best way to seamlessly do this?**

My biggest concern is I don't want every single user to have to go through the "forgot password" process. Regarding passwords. As I understand, there's no supported way to get at the passwords in order to convert them to membership users. **Is there an unsupported way to grab the passwords?**

There are about 1000 users, and they log into the system rarely -- maybe a few times per year. Point being: there will be a huge % of users that won't log in until the old system is dead and gone.

My current thought is that we will need to implement two workflows:

1. Before migration to the new server, anyone that logs in will be authenticated with Windows, and their account automatically converted to a membership user. We will have their password from our custom login page.
2. After migration, anyone logging in that hasn't been converted to membership will have to go through the "forgot password" routine. We would present a message to them explaining why.

So bottom line: **Is there a way to do this without requiring users to go through the forgot password process at all?**

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you cannot get the passwords from the windows accounts, you could import the users, create a password and send out an email to users with their new password or you could send a link for users to login and create a password or request a password reset given their email address?